How to diagnose and fix odd role-linked behaviour with D7/webform/Stripe?
I'm seeing strange behaviour on a D7 webform that is integrated into CiviCRM using webform_civicrm, where I'm enabling paid event registrations.
The form captures detail about 4 contacts (two individuals and their organisations), and lets the user register the second contact for either one or two paid events, using the Stripe extension.
Completing the form as an anonymous user works great. The payment stuff is on the second page of the form, and presents the data accurately about the user, the events they have been registered for, the sub-total inc. tax for each event, and the grand total. All good.
However, if I attempt to complete the form as a logged-in user, using the role that most of our users are likely to have, this summary information is incorrect. The event name/s is/are not presented, the sub-totals don't have the tax added on (the ex.tax totals are shown), and hence the total charged to the card is incorrect.
Better yet, if I attempt to complete the form as user 1, I get a result that is halfway between the two: one of the events is presented and accounted for with the tax included, while the other is broken in the same way as if I was logged in as an average user.
I've gone through the roles and permissions and can't see anything that might be pertinent.
Any ideas about what might be going wrong here would be most welcome.
Versions: Civi 5.78.3, Stripe 6.11.3, Drupal 7.101, Webform 7.x-4.26 and Webform-CiviCRM 7.x-5.8

It feels like a custom module/extension/code elsewhere influence - a bit  too complex for Drupal/Civi Rules.
